# How do I write a vim function that will return a string from a previous line in the file?

Tags: vim

Given the following 5 lines:

```
describe 'trueness', ->
  it 'is really, really, really true', ->
    expect(true).to.eq true
    expect(true).to.eq true
    expect(true).to.eq true
```

Is there a way I could could write a function in vim script that:

- When run anywhere on Line 2, 3, 4, or 5 of the above code, will return the string `it is really, really, really true`?
- When run anywhere on Line 1, will return the string `trueness`?

(I'm looking to write a function that will allow me to run certain `mocha` specs from `vim`, and the only way to do this is to pass `mocha` a string representing the name of the spec to run.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple iteration with a `while` loop will do that for you. You obtain the current line's contents with `getline()` and extract the quoted string with `matchstr()` and a proper regular expression, like this:

```
function! GetQuotedAbove()
    let lnum = line('.')
    while lnum > 0
        let quoted = matchstr(getline(lnum), "'[^']*'")
        if ! empty(quoted)
            return quoted
        endif
        let lnum -= 1
    endwhile
    return ''
endfunction
```